# Liquibase update using maven pom

Tags: liquibase

I am getting below error when performing an update using liquibase maven update goal.

> liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: Error parsing line 4459 column 108 of db.changelogdiff.xml: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'objectQuotingStrategy' is not allowed to appear in element 'changeSet'.

The diff generated changelog file(using jenkins + Maven) has objectQuotingStrategy as a changeset attribute. This results in above error.

I am using **Liquibase-maven plugin 3.5**, My **jenkins** is **2.0**

---Solved--
The xsi:schemaLocation in my changelog xml was pointing to old version. Corrected to latest version which solved the issue. Thanks Gile for the headsup :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your diff generated changelog file has been done according to

`http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd`

but it seems liquibase maven update is parsing it according to

`http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd`

or older, that still doesn't allow attribute 'objectQuotingStrategy' in element 'changeSet.

So I would double-check liquibase-core version in pom.xml , eventually upgrading from [MVN repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.liquibase/liquibase-core).

Comment: Thanks for the response gile. The liquibase core is at version 3.5.0 in my pom.xml

Comment: ---Solved-- The xsi:schemaLocation in my changelog xml was pointing to old version. Corrected to latest version which solved the issue. Thanks Gile for the headsup :-)